# How to update TextFormField content after onPressed of a prefixIcon with FutureBuilder?

Tags: flutter

I just started a small flutter project. I have a onPressed property inside a suffixIcon and the onPressed itself has a FutureBuilder inside of it. The future function is async (I am using the geolocator package) and it returns the coordinates of the device. I want to refresh the TextFieldForm content with those coordinates when the user presses the suffixIcon but the TextFieldForm is not being updated, although the onPressed is working as I have a print in the function to know if it's working properly. Here is the code of the TextFormBuilder, and below is the complete code. Any help would be apreciated

```
TextFormField(
              controller: myController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.location_searching),
                  onPressed:(){
                    FutureBuilder<String>(
                      future: _obtenerUbicacion(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          myController.text =  snapshot.data;
                        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                        }
                        // By default, show a loading spinner.
                        return CircularProgressIndicator();
                      },
                    );
                  }
                  ,
                ),
                hintText: 'Ingrese su ubicación',
              ),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Por favor ingrese su ubicación';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
```

Here is the complete code of the App

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';



void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent[100]),
        home: Localizador());
  }
}

class Localizador extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LocalizadorState createState() => _LocalizadorState();
}

class _LocalizadorState extends State<Localizador> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  Future<Serviciabilidad> futureServiciabilidad;
  final myController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget _coordenadas() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              controller: myController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.location_searching),
                  onPressed:(){
                    FutureBuilder<String>(
                      future: _obtenerUbicacion(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          myController.text =  snapshot.data;
                        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                        }
                        // By default, show a loading spinner.
                        return CircularProgressIndicator();
                      },
                    );
                  }
                  ,
                ),
                hintText: 'Ingrese su ubicación',
              ),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Por favor ingrese su ubicación';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // Validate will return true if the form is valid, or false if
                  // the form is invalid.
                  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    futureServiciabilidad = obtenerServiciabilidad();
                  }
                },
                child: Text('Enviar'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(title: Text('MyAPP')), body: _coordenadas());
  }
}

Future<String> _obtenerUbicacion() async {
  Position position = await Geolocator()
      .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
  //print(position.toString());
  String pos = (position.latitude.toString())+ " " + (position.longitude.toString());
  print(pos);
  return pos;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
The way you use `FutureBuilder` is incorrect. in your case, you can directly use `async await` 
code snippet

```
prefixIcon: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.location_searching),
          onPressed: () async {
            var pos = await _obtenerUbicacion();
            setState(() {
              myController.text = pos;
            });
          },
        ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent[100]),
        home: Localizador());
  }
}

class Localizador extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LocalizadorState createState() => _LocalizadorState();
}

class _LocalizadorState extends State<Localizador> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  //Future<Serviciabilidad> futureServiciabilidad;
  final myController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget _coordenadas() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              controller: myController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.location_searching),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    var pos = await _obtenerUbicacion();
                    setState(() {
                      myController.text = pos;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                hintText: 'Ingrese su ubicación',
              ),
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Por favor ingrese su ubicación';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // Validate will return true if the form is valid, or false if
                  // the form is invalid.
                  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    //futureServiciabilidad = obtenerServiciabilidad();
                  }
                },
                child: Text('Enviar'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(title: Text('MyAPP')), body: _coordenadas());
  }
}

Future<String> _obtenerUbicacion() async {
  Position position = await Geolocator()
      .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
  //print(position.toString());
  String pos =
      (position.latitude.toString()) + " " + (position.longitude.toString());
  print(pos);
  return pos;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked like a charm. Just wondering if my code didn't worked because I didn't used the initState method. Got the FutureBuilder implementation in my code from https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data#5-display-the-data but didn't used de initState

Comment: Need to reproduce, could you post your reproduce code to a new question? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using `setState` should do the job

```dart
if(snapshot.hasData) {
    setState(() => myController.text =  snapshot.data);
}
```